# How to download from client a csv generated in a sequence?

Tags: convertigo

I have a form on a page from which I call a sequence that build a csv file. I would like this file to be downloadable directly from client browser after the sequence call.
What is the c8o solution ?
Thank you

Comment: To you use the Mobile Builder ? This is for a browser or a cordova environment ?

Comment: I use Mobile Builder, but this is for browser environment. The user fill in a form, post datas to a sequence. The sequence get datas from couchDB and generate a csv. I would like to be able to send back to user the csv generated file for download

Comment: Would you like a link to download the file or an automatic download in response of the form submit (sequence call)?

Comment: I would definitely prefer the automatic download in response of the form submit, but the link may be an acceptable solution if no other solution is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1/ Your sequence call returns the URL of the generated CSV file on the Convertigo Server (inside project or workspace) and you create a link in Mobile Builder that points to this URL. Drawback is that user have to right-click the link to download the file or else it may be displayed in browser. I tried to add 'download' attribute to link but I was unsuccessful

2/ Same as above but instead of pointing directly to the CSV file, the link points to a new Convertigo sequence called in .bin ([Convertigo requesters](https://www.convertigo.com/document/latest/reference-manual/convertigo-mbaas-server/interfaces-to-convertigo/http-protocol-interface-to-convertigo/convertigo-urls/convertigo-requesters/)), the response will be a binary file that browser will download. This sequence must return a specific XML tag:

```
<attachment content-type="application/csv" local-url="D:\COMMON\C8O\sc757_64\workspace\DLFile\repository\data.csv" name="data.csv" type="attachment"/>
```

This method also implies a link the user have to manually click.

You can have more details on how to do it in this sample project : [DLFile.car](https://convertigo-download.s3.amazonaws.com/webrepository/projects/DLFile.car)

I am using a JS trick to trigger the click event on the link to automatically perform the file download:

In Mobile Builder HTML :

```
<a class="class1567759665690" id="csvFile" href="http://localhost:18080/convertigo/projects/DLFile/.bin?__sequence=fileBin&amp;name=data.csv&amp;filePath=D%3A%5CCOMMON%5CC8O%5Csc757_64%5Cworkspace%5CDLFile%5Crepository%5Cdata.csv">data.csv</a>
```

In a CustomAction component:

```
setTimeout(() => {
            document.getElementById("csvFile").click();
        }, 500);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you ! It works as expected using the second possibility.
I tested on the convertigo trial server but it does not work. I suspect an insuffisant permission for creating file and/or for accessing to the DL url. Can you confirm ?

Comment: In the DLFile sample project, I used a Windows path with backslash (\ => %5C). trial.convertigo.net is running under Linux. Path should use slashes (/ => %2F). So, file path can be calculated using context.getProjectDirectory()+"/repository/data.csv". This should also work for Windows path (no need to replace slash to backslash, as I did in the sample project.). The DLFile project is deployed to trial and it works for me. Use encodeURIComponent JS function to encode special characters in the file path parameter to send to the sequence.